# javaFX, two mouseEvents at once

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I'm trying to write a window in my program for drawing lines using a mouse. I've come with this solution so far:

```
public class TrackEditor extends Stage
{
    TrackDescription editedTrackDescription;
    double startX, startY;
    LineTo line;
    MoveTo move;
    boolean pressed;

    public TrackEditor()
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        this.setTitle("New Game");
        this.setResizable(false);   

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        SquareGrid squareGrid = new SquareGrid();
        Pane drawingPane = new Pane();
        Pane activePane = new Pane();
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(squareGrid,drawingPane, activePane);        
        drawingPane.getChildren().add(path);
        activePane.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
            pressed = true;
            startX = me.getX();
            startY = me.getY();
            move = new MoveTo(me.getX(), me.getY());            
            path.getElements().add(move);
        });
        activePane.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent me) -> {
            pressed = false;
            line = new LineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());           
            path.getElements().add(line);
        });
        activePane.setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent me) -> {
            if(pressed)
            {
                activePane.getChildren().clear();
                Line temporaryLine = new Line(startX, startY, me.getX(), me.getY());
                activePane.getChildren().add(temporaryLine);
            }
        });       


        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);


        this.setScene(scene);
        this.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);       
        this.sizeToScene();
        this.show();
    }    
}
```

However, as I've observed, the temporary line is not drawn when mouse button is pressed. Is there some kind of conflict between events `MousePressed` and `Mouse Released`, or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to detect when the mouse is dragged (i.e. when it is moved with the button down). You don't need to track the `pressed` flag yourself, the underlying event system will do this for you.

```
activePane.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
    startX = me.getX();
    startY = me.getY();
    move = new MoveTo(me.getX(), me.getY());            
    path.getElements().add(move);
});
activePane.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent me) -> {
    line = new LineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());           
    path.getElements().add(line);
});
activePane.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) -> {
    activePane.getChildren().clear();
    Line temporaryLine = new Line(startX, startY, me.getX(), me.getY());
    activePane.getChildren().add(temporaryLine);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about this event at all